# I've been failing to enumerate(list) all channels in the server using "ctx.guild.channels" in discord.py "Text Channels,Voice Channels"

Tags: discord.py

I want to list all the channels(with information of name ,id etc) in a server using discord.py . To achieve it , I've written the below code.

```
@bot.command()
async def enumurate_channels(ctx):

    channels = ctx.guild.channels

    print("The number of channels", len(channels))

    for channel in channels:
        print(channel.name)
```

And please assume that we gonna handle the server which contains 2 channels , one of them is "general" in Text Channel(s) and the other is "General" in Voice Channel(s)

As I run the above command , I got the below.

```
The number of channels 4
Text Channels
Voice Channels
general
General
```

The firstly shown these two     `Text Channels,Voice Channels` are quite annoying since these are not actually channels.

How can I correctly enumerate the any channel in the server?

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick solutions is to use attribute `.type`

```
@bot.command()
async def enumurate_channels(ctx):

    channels = ctx.guild.channels

    print("The number of channels", len(channels))

    for channel in channels:
        print(channel.type) # CHANGED HERE.
```

Possible outputs of `channel.type`   are "category","text","voice"

Handle this attribute `.type` to do what you want to do.